# If number entered > 5 then show message using JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, numbers

Using Jquery is it possible to show a message "Number should not be more than 5" when number entered more than 5 in input field. Once entered value less than 5 then message should hide.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Get to Googling!

Comment: You've pretty much stated the logic that you want to perform, even pseudocodely stated the events in a sense.  What specific issues are you having implementing this logic?

Comment: Can we not just give someone an answer and instead encourage them to put in some effort first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#num").on("keyup",function(){
  if($(this).val()>5)
     alert("The number entered is greater than 5");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="num" type="number" value="click"/>
```

Comment: Great! works well. Thanks. I have updated the script to hide the message. let me know if its wrong.

Comment: $("#quantity").on("keyup",function(){
  if($(this).val()>5)
   $("p").show();
   else
   $("p").hide();
});

Comment: thanks. This is correct just *display:none*  the *<p>*  first load page

Comment: Thanks Farhad. If I want to disabled that input field as well at same time, How could can we have multiple actions once a condition met? For Example i want to add "$("#quantity").addClass("disabled");" along with showing that "P" tag. Please help. thx in advance

Comment: @SameerAli hi. for add disabled **$(this).attr('disabled','disabled')** and for remove disabled **$(this).removeAttr('disabled')**

Answer (score 0):

`if (Number($('#field').val()) <= 5) { alert('Number should not be more than 5'); }`

Comment: This code suppose to be written on focus?

Comment: this can be used in `$('#field').keyup(function(){ //event });` or any another that triggers while input. Focus will fire only when you first focused on input. Maybe `blur` event will suit your needs.

Comment: You flipped the logic.

Comment: Thanks Max, this also works :)